# what is a good tool to restore files within their path when you rm -r from root?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery

Tried foremost but as far as i can see it only recovers the files itself.

Is there some tool which reproduces the directory tree? I mean according to `path` of a file. does the ext4 filesystem even keep `path` when removing the file?

Comment: Restore from your most recent backup.  That's what backups are for.  You _do_ have a backup, right?

Comment: sadly not :/ This is so awkward, I shouldn't have asked xD.. oh my god i feel so sad and stupid..

Comment: I'm sorry that you've lost your data structure; I hope nothing too critical was destroyed with the errant `rm`.

Comment: The question might appear awkward, but it is legitimate. One may need to restore the files between the last backup and the moment of the disaster. Say for instance that you saved a crucial file 5 minutes ago and the last backup was 4 hours ago. The backup would be no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's extundelete, magicrescue and testdisk, and more. Of these, extundelete best suits your requirement. Explore the `--restore-directory /some/path` option. You can at least get your files named correctly, as they were named before your mistake. You can also limit the restoration within a date range.

Comment: thanks. thats a good list to begin with. I make an image dump and work my way throw the fs over time. Already have a new install running. there was nothing on data i need immediately, thank god.